# Empty space in UIImageView when using scaleAspectFit

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Here is [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOqUr.png) of my issue. My problem is that I have an tiny empty space on the right side of my UIImageView that is constrained to the view of my view controller. It's green because of the background I set, and it is more prominent on my device. It's weird because the image should fit the whole screen considering the image was taken on the phone itself and I am using scaleAspectFit.

```
let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.backgroundColor = .green
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    return imageView
}()
```

Here is the code for the constraints:

```
func setupImageView() {
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    let imageViewConstraints = [
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(imageViewConstraints)
}
```

I am basically setting the image using `self.imageView.image` and I end up with a empty space on the right side that is only noticeable when using bright colors as the imageView background. Not sure if this is a bug. The only reason I'm not using fill is because I want to maintain the aspect while showing the whole image.

Comment: its not necessory that an image taken from same device will show on complete screen just because of using scale aspectFit, scale aspect fit means, a scale where image will not be stretched or compressed :)

Comment: Okay, I got it to work by scaling the image down. It was 1080 x 1920, and the imageView was 320 x 568. Doesn't that mean the amount I scale down will be different for each device?

Comment: It seems to be working as long as the UIImage is the size of the image view. Thanks.

Comment: but i think it will work for only 320 x 568 it will not work as expected for  devices with larger screen.

Comment: yes, because the imageView is a different size on every screen depending on constraints?

Comment: no,  due to photo size :) and rasolution and property you used scaleaspectfit

Answer (score 0):

The contentMode `scaleAspectFit` will keep the scale of the image, display the whole content of the image. Because your photo scale is same to the screen, if your imageView height is less than screen, the image display width will be less than screen too, which causes the background `green` color shows. 
To ensure the imageView fits the screen, you can add border on it:

```
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in your imageView{
`imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill`
}